# Instagram :get access token using ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, instagram

I need to get the user access token for Instagram using AJAX. I tried:

```
var request = $.ajax({
    dataType: "jsonp",
    type: 'GET',
    url: "https://instagram.com/oauth/authorize/",
    data: { 
        client_id: CLIENT_ID,
        redirect_uri: 'SamePage',
        response_type: 'token'
        }
    });
    request.success(showdata);
    request.fail(showerror);
});
```

I get error

```
Object { readyState=4,  status=200,  statusText="parsererror"}
```

> SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'

Comment: The flow isn't that way, and you can't get access token using AJAX. You must redirect the user to Instagram, and then they come back back to your page with the token you need.

Comment: The error indicates that the endpoint is returning HTML (as the first character of the response is `<`) not JSONP. Check the network tab of the console to see exactly what the request returns. Are you sure that Instagram returns data in JSONP format, and has CORS enabled?

Comment: @ Adam is there a plugin that can get access token using ajax for Instagram?